# Why is it impossible to use a var in a type definition ?

Tags: typescript

```
type myType = 'A';
const myVar = 'A';

let a: 'A'; // OK
let b: myType; // OK
let c: myVar; // ERROR : cannot find name 'myVar'
```

Why isn't it possible to use a var as a type ? Shouldn't it be possible ?

Answer (score 2):

`myVar` is a constant, you cannot type a variable as a constant, you can specify that a variable has the same type as the constant:

```
let c: typeof myVar;
```

Note that since the constant is "A" the above declaration is the same as

```
let c: "A";
```

So the only value assignable tp `c` is the constant value `"A"`

Comment: let a = 'A' ; 
let b: a; // Error too, const seems to have nothing to do with that.

Comment: yes it's not related to const. You can't say that the type of a variable IS another variable, you can say they have the same type `let a = 'A'; let b: typeof a`

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to delcare a variable in TypeScript

`var, let, const & Type (Type will be custom datatype)`

`let & var` are quite similar while `const` prevent re-assignment to a variable. You can find diff between var & let [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html).

`const` is something which is constant and it's behaviour in TypeScript is same as C#. In C#, we also can't use const as type.

**And to mainly answer your question - myVar is a variable not a type so you can't use a variable as type.**